# Refreshing field's state

Tags: blackberry

In my application I'm using custom fields, with "set***" methods wich changes some parameters of this fields (background image, for example). thay work allmost fine, only one problem: I'm setting and changing parameters of this fields like below:

```
    record = new UIButton("RECORD", Field.FOCUSABLE, kButtonWidth/3-5, kButtonHeight);
    vfm2.add(Record); //I tryed this befor setters and after: no different
    record.setBackgroundImage("buttonDark.png", "buttonDark.png", "buttonDark.png");
    record.setTitleFontSize(Display.getHeight()/40);
    record.setTitle("RECORD");
```

When the screen with this fields are pushed, my field looks like no setters were called (but it was: I checked this via log messages). Field's state refreshes only after it is focused (I'm calling same setters on `onFocus` and on `onUnFocus`, where I have `invalidate()`). Is there any way to refrash it on screen appear? In iPhone SDK, for example, there is `viewDidAppear` method, that colled when view(screen) did appear. Is there any same in blackberry? Or any other solution?

---

Here is my code of `UIButton` class:

```
public class UIButton extends Field 
{       
    private String title = null;
    private Font font;
    private int fontSize;
    private int color;
    private int horizontalAligment;
    private int state;  //0 - normal;   1 - focused;    2 - HightLighted;

    private int height;
    private int width;

    private EncodedImage currentPicture;
    private EncodedImage onPicture;
    private EncodedImage offPicture;
    private EncodedImage lightPicture;

    public UIButton(long style, int Widgh, int Height)
    {
        super(style);

        height = Height;
        width = Widgh;
        fontSize = Display.getHeight()/20;
        FontFamily ff = getFont().getFontFamily();
        font = ff.getFont(0, fontSize);
        title = "";
        color = Color.WHITE;
        state = 0;
        horizontalAligment = DrawStyle.HCENTER;

        onPicture = offPicture = lightPicture = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("buttonDark.png");
        currentPicture = offPicture;

    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitleColor (int Color) {
        color = Color;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setFrame (int Height, int Width) {
        height = Height;
        width = Width;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTitle (String Title) {
        title = Title;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTitleHorizontalAligment (int hAligment) {
        horizontalAligment = hAligment;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBackgroundImage (String forStateNurmal, String forStateFocused, String forStateHightlighted) {
        onPicture = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(forStateFocused);
        offPicture = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(forStateNurmal);
        lightPicture = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(forStateHightlighted);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setState (int State) {
        state = State;
        switch (state) {
        case 0: {
            currentPicture = offPicture;
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            currentPicture = onPicture;
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            currentPicture = lightPicture;
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    public void setTitleFont (Font Font) {
        font = Font;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setTitleFontSize (int FontSize) {
        fontSize = FontSize;
        FontFamily ff = font.getFontFamily();
        font = ff.getFont(0, fontSize);
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() 
    {
        return height;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() 
    {
        return  width;
    }


    protected void onFocus(int direction) 
    {
        super.onFocus(direction);
        this.setState(0);
    }


    protected void onUnfocus() 
    {
        if (state!=2) this.setState(1);
    }


    protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) 
    {
        super.drawFocus(graphics, on);
    }


    protected void layout(int width, int height) 
    {
        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(),getPreferredHeight());
    }


    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        ResizeImage r = new ResizeImage();
        currentPicture = r.sizeImage(currentPicture, width-2, height-2);
        graphics.drawBitmap(1, 1, width-2, height-2, currentPicture.getBitmap(), 0, 0);
        if (title.getBytes().length>0) {

            graphics.setColor(color);
            graphics.setFont(font);

            int x = 0;
            if (horizontalAligment == DrawStyle.LEFT) x = 2;
            graphics.drawText(title, x, (height-font.getHeight())/2, 
                    (int)( getStyle() & DrawStyle.VCENTER & horizontalAligment | DrawStyle.HALIGN_MASK ), width );
        }
    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
    {
        fieldChangeNotify(1);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also call invalidate() after  Record.setBackgroundImage("buttonDark.png", "buttonDark.png", "buttonDark.png");

Comment: tnx for response, but this is not working.

Comment: Try to call this.setState(0) in setBackgroundImage(). it may be, i am n't sure, help you to change the image in unfocused state.

Comment: you are right. I fogot that my `EncodedImage currentPicture` is't a pointer, so it was not changed when I changed other images.

Comment: Glad to know your problem solved :)

Comment: could you post this as an answer? I need to approve something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to change currentPicture in setBackgroundImage(). Try `currentPicture = offPicture`
or call `this.setState(0)`  in `setBackgroundImage()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a very strong convention in Java to name local and field identifiers with lower case letters.  So seeing "Record" as a local variable name is quite confusing.

---

Without the code for your custom field, UIButton, it is impossible to answer your question here. Built-in components for BlackBerry OS would behave correctly given this sequence of add and sets, so it is likely your custom field isn't following the BlackBerry conventions with layout and painting.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the set** methods *before* you add the field to the manager you should not have this problem in the first place. Is there a reason you call them after?

Comment: I sad, I tryed it before and after. there is no differet. But I'm adding vfm2 to screen before this code. should I do this after?